# openframework samples are compiled but crashing on many places at runtime

Tags: opengl, opencv, runtime-error, openframeworks

previously i was using opengl and opencv explicitly and they works fine on my computer so i am sure its not because of any graphic card problem. What i am trying is openframework and i have compiled the library successfully. Also the sample compiled 100% correct but when i run the application it get crash.

After investigating it i found the place where it get crahed or access violation.

the sample is \examples\video\videoGrabberExample

```
videoTexture.loadData(videoInverted, camWidth,camHeight, GL_RGB);
```

after further debuging i found its crashing place on two places on each project

```
 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); //inside the class ofTexture.
```

and

```
  ofEnableBlendMode(OF_BLENDMODE_ALPHA);
```

or any blending option it crashed.

this seems like opnengl error but i am not sure what to do next. So my request is if anyone has experience in openframework then kindly guide me why its not working ?

Comment: Can you try the same code on a different machine(preferably with a different GPU) and see if you get the same crashes ?

Comment: yes i tried on 2 more different machines and it crashed like mine. Any idea what should i do to run it?